# Uploading image files to server without using HTML form element

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to upload a pic on server without using html form tag. Is there a simple to do this. Actually, i have been building an app where user will be allowed to either upload his pic or take a new one from webcam and if user click the upload button then the pic move to the server.
When user upload pic and press upload button, it works fine because i have been using HTML input tag with type='file' but when i take pic from webcam and render it on HTML5 canvas tag then i click the upload button, no pic move to the server because there is no file in the input tag. In both cases, i am using the same canvas element and img tag to show it the user.

IS there a way to upload without using form element or is there a way that i can assign an image object that i get from Canavas element into the same form input element??

all answers are welcome

Many thanks in advance

server side code

```
    function bytesToSize1024($bytes, $precision = 2) {
    $unit = array('B','KB','MB');
    return @round($bytes / pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($bytes, 1024)))), $precision).' '.$unit[$i];
}

$sFileName = $_FILES['image_file']['name'];
$sFileType = $_FILES['image_file']['type'];
$sFileSize = bytesToSize1024($_FILES['image_file']['size'], 1);

 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1;
$error=$_FILES["image_file"]["error"];


$uploaddir = '/var/www/example119/upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image_file']['name']);

  if(!empty($_FILES))
  {
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], "$target$sFileName")) 
     {
     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['image_file']['name']). " has been uploaded...";
     } 
     else {
     echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file. {$error}";
     }
  }
  else
    {
    echo "_files is empty";
    }
```

Javascipt code to make an HTTPrequest

```
function startUploading() {
    // cleanup all temp states

    iPreviousBytesLoaded = 0;
    var oProgress = document.getElementById('progress');
    oProgress.style.display = 'block';
    oProgress.style.width = '0px';

    // get form data for POSTing
    //var vFD = document.getElementById('upload_form').getFormData(); // for FF3
    var vFD = new FormData(document.getElementById('upload_form')); // this is for when user upload from browser box
    var vvFD=document.getElementById('preview1'); //added by TODO to test
    // create XMLHttpRequest object, adding few event listeners, and POSTing our data
    var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    oXHR.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);
    oXHR.addEventListener('load', uploadFinish, false);
    oXHR.addEventListener('error', uploadError, false);
    oXHR.addEventListener('abort', uploadAbort, false);
    oXHR.open('POST', 'example_upload/upload.php');
    //oXHR.send(vFD);
    oXHR.send(vvFD);

    // set inner timer
    oTimer = setInterval(doInnerUpdates, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try sending the image data via POST. It doesn't have any size restrictions, and the contents can follow any format.

Comment: Just out of interest, how would you select the file to upload? Surely you need a file input to give the user access to their file system..? If there is another way (without using Flash or any other plugins that the user might not have) then I'd love to know it.

Comment: If you are sending an actual file, you of course use a file input. But if -- like the question suggests -- want to upload some arbitrary data to the server and store it there, you can use the POST method. There is no way not involving Flash or other plugins or the good, old file input field that gives you access to the user's file system, and that is of course just a reasonable security precaution.

Comment: Ah yes good ol' security precautions - the same ones that make it so bloomin' difficult to customise the look and feel of the file input!

Comment: Exactly. Which sometimes makes the wall next to your computer look strangely welcoming to your head. But even banging the head doesn't help.

Comment: i take an image from webcam and render it to HTML5 canvas element, then i have an upload button, by pressing this button, i convert the HTML5 canvas into an image and want to save that image.
Hope you get my issue??

Comment: Yes. You can put the data in a hidden field and send it via POST, and store it as an image on your server side when the form has been submitted. I hope I'm being clear with my answer here.

Comment: I am in rented accommodation so have to pay for any damages to the property when I leave - I find it more stress relieving and cheaper to just kick the computer lol

Comment: @MiladNaseri: yes you are right and i am getting your point, but i am newbie in php as well, im an RoR developer, but i have to this task in php, i have been sharing the server side script that i have been using, can you plz suggest some change in it??

Comment: How can I see your script? I don't see any links here.

Comment: Saw it now. Will take a look at it.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy Well, I guess we have to all make do with what we can :-D

Comment: @MiladNaseri: plz also have a look at javascript that i just added

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6724/discussion-between-nadeem-yasin-and-milad-naseri)

Comment: @MiladNaseri: hi frnd, difinitely i'll mark it as answer but still i am not able to resolve the my issue, can you help me a bit more? as per out chat.

Comment: @MiladNaseri: yes i have found the answer, to access the data server in $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] variable rather $_POST, thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you can't upload without form tag. There are workarounds that seem to use Ajax, such as an iframe or using Flash.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there a way that i change the src of input file tag, rather than opening a browser box to select file, for example if i have some img tag and want to save that image from an img tag to the server??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use form elements then how are you going to take the input from user?
You can use Flash, Java but it only makes your work more difficult.. I may recommend using the form input , process it using Javascript and then send it to a PHP Uploader Script.You can either redirect the user to that PHP page and do the work there or do it with AJAX and take an integer which will represent your new uploaded image then insert it in your database or wherever you store them and show user his new image..

Comment: is there a way that i change the src of input file tag, rather than opening a browser box to select file, for example if i have some img tag and want to save that image from an img tag to the server??

Comment: i take an image from webcam and render it to HTML5 canvas element, then i have an upload button, by pressing this button, i convert the HTML5 canvas into an image and want to save that image. Hope you get my issue?? –

Comment: You can't change the SRC of an input file tag. It goes against all sorts of security issues.